# Add HTML-Tags with JS | chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a Chrome extension.

At one point I have to add some new html-tags with JavaScript but it didn't worked.
So I tried this little example on my local webserver and in my extension.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>||Working with elements||</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">This is old</div>
  <script>
   document.body.onload = addElement;

    function addElement () { 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("This is new!"); 
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/yz9v8479/

As you can see it works fine for a normal webpage.
But it wont work in my extension.

[image]

But my code is the same. I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: It is not allowed to have code only in an external link (like jsfiddle). StackOverflow enforces it, so you decided to willingly bypass it by making the link a code snippet. Don't do that. Code you want debugged _must be in the question itself_ - it's fine to add a jsfiddle link after that.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I changed it. @Xan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [inline script won't be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). Try extracting the JS code to an external JavaScript file and include it as a script tag.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "36738850",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Your browser action title",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>||Working with elements||</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">This is old</div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("This is new!");
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
}
```

Comment: @Paili, it would help a lot if you could add your code in the post. I have edited the answer and provided a sample code.

Comment: Oh, I stupidly forgot to change the manifest.json! Thanks a lot :)